# How to implement android broadcast receiver kind of programming in Windows phone

Tags: android, windows-phone-8

I want to create a Windows Phone application which can respond when phone rings.in android we can use broadcast receiver can any one suggest me an equivalent concept to broadcast receiver in Windows phone 8 or 8.1

Comment: the equivalent concept is: "go back to android". Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows phone does not have any api like that

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the windows phone does not expose any api or events for when the phone rings